# How to find the area of only garbage collected in sea using SIFT algorithm in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, object-recognition

I have used SIFT to locate keypoints in some garbage part collected in ocean. How can i automatically calculate area of all garbage only? In the given figure blue points are the keypoints formed through SIFT algorithm. I'm new to matlab.

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9x7R.jpg)

[KeyPoints in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WYIY.jpg)

Comment: Try a different aproach: extract the blue channel from your image and then segment out the garbage

Comment: "Area" as in pixel area right? not real life area.

Comment: try using the otsu threshold and calculate the contour area